# Android want to show image loading progress

Tags: android, progress-bar, image-loading

I am loading image from  a given array of URL .I want to show the progress of the image loading similar to the  below screenshot.

[image: image loader indication]

is it possible to get their loading indication?

Comment: are you running a loop to load each element in the array?

Answer (score 0):

Use ProgressBar with in Relative Layout hold ImageView , and show ProgressBar while loading Done in AsyncTask , when Done , setVisibility To InVisible and Rest ProgressBar To Zero